# Insert into Oracle DB using Java

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to insert values in a table on  my oracle server, however, the program keeps running and doesn't execute. This is my code:

This is how I connect to the database:

```
try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@abc.xxx.edu:1521:soeorcl","123",
                    "123");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
```

Then I try to insert the values in the table:

```
 try {
            PreparedStatement prepareStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO MYTABLE (USERID, USERNAME, EMAILADDRESS, PHONENUMBER, PROFILEPICTURE )"
                    + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            prepareStatement.setString(1, "10");
            prepareStatement.setString(2, "ALI");
            prepareStatement.setString(3, "gdgrgrregeg");
            prepareStatement.setString(4, "0501977498");
            prepareStatement.setNull(5, NULL);
            prepareStatement.execute();
 } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("IT DOES NOT WORK");
        }
```

The program gets stuck at `prepareStatement.execute();` I have already checked the constraints and they work if I manually add them on the oracle server but the above code does not work.

Any ideas? Suggestions?

Comment: Where is the `connection` code ? Is `autoCommit` set to `false` ?

Comment: Leave a space between `PROFILEPICTURE) and VALUES`

Comment: lock on table? Can you see your inserting session on db?

Comment: If it's indeed stalled at the insert, it's probably that some other transaction somewhere (typically in your database browsing tool) is locking the table and is still waiting to be committed.

Comment: Printing prepared  statement and logging exception can help u.

Comment: There are several possible ways how an insert can be blocked: another uncommitted insert that inserted the **exact same** PK value, an uncommited `delete` that deleted the row with the PK value you want to insert, a trigger on the table that causes the locking or another transaction that explicitly locked the complete table using `lock table ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the sql string used in your prepared statement and then copy paste it and run it manually. Often times there are some misspellings or missing spaces in the string. In your case it could be an error from the way the statement is written.

I noticed that you need a space before VALUES.